# Asp.Net Mvc DevExpress Display GridView Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, devexpress

I am developing a project with Asp.Net Mvc. I use devexpress gridview as gridview to show records in database. But the data is not displayed on the screen when the page is loaded. It is loaded after processing on the gridview as in the video. What can I do to keep the page coming when it loads?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qeMYYOw9gMNxTssyBPrVW0BW_y8ksOtn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't attach videos to questions, especially when they are hosted externally. Instead, explain what you do in the video, the results, and the expected results in the question body.

Comment: Hi guys, problem is fixed.